# How to normalize mortality in determining lethal concentration of toxins or pesticides?

Tags: normalization, biostatistics, dose-response

A certain set of pesticide concentrations is selected to dose the animals to determine its acute toxicity. Technically, with increasing concentrations, the mortality should increase, but that does not occur. In some cases, in higher dose category the mortality will be less than that of the preceding or earlier dose category. How to overcome this problem? If there is any way around like through mathematical formula or any paper that sheds light on this aspect please enlighten me.

The data is as follows: five treatments and seven fish per treatment

- First treatment: none dead
- Second treatment: two out of seven dead
- Third treatment: one out of seven dead
- Fourth treatment: all dead
- Fifth treatment: All dead

Comment: Could you be more specific about what the problem is?  You describe a form of hormesis.  Is the issue that your chosen model does not accommodate that?  Or do you expect hormesis not to be real and want some way to make it disappear statistically?  Or something else?

Comment: @whuber My read is that OP does not *expect* hormesis but is confused about whether their data suggest it. I believe their question is equivalent to "how can I choose an 'LD50' when my data don't have a clear boundary where half of the animals die".

Comment: @Bryan Thank you; I would guess that too -- but so much is unstated in this question (what was the planned analysis, what were the expected results, what form(s) of dose-response models are considered plausible, and so on) that some clarification could be helpful.

Comment: @whuber I think OP is novice in statistical analysis and would appreciate guidance on all those things :) In a comment before migrating I had asked "What is the particular toxin for which increasing concentrations don't increase mortality? Or are you referring to statistical variation in observed mortality due to limited sample sizes?", OP responded "exactly, the chemical i am working on is pyrethroid pesticide and I have selected five different set of pesticide concentrations for which seven fish are exposed for each concentration"

Comment: @Bryan Again thanks: that background information is helpful.  I tend to presume that anyone who has invested time and resources in conducting an experiment has previously considered these issues of data analysis and underlying theory and therefore is prepared to explain them, but in fact that often is not the case.

Comment: @BryanKrause, thank you. yes, I am a beginner in statistical analysis and I am here to learn from anyone. All I know is certain statistical tests that can be performed based on data type. For determination of lethal concentration, Probit analysis is employed and I have applied it too.

Comment: @whuber, I was the one who asked the question and I am new to the platform. I wasn't ware that participants would be highly specific and section in which one should post the question. I just posted it in biology section with a toxicology tag.  Please tell me, What else do i need to provide here?

Comment: Just make as clear a statement of your problem as you can.  It's preferable *not* to try to couch it in statistical terms: use your own language (nontechnical if possible, to keep your audience wide).  If we don't understand it, we will say so!

Comment: @whuber, So as mentioned in the question, the mortality I have observed and recorded is not the way how it should be, i.e. increasing mortality as dose concentration increases. How can one solve such issue? Applying probit will still give is some value, but it is not correct i assume. So do we have any method that can overcome this issue?

Comment: The difficulty is that statistics isn't intended to force the world into displaying "what it should be."  Are you trying to discover the dose-response curve or are you trying to demonstrate that the data are consistent with your expectations? Ultimately you have to *estimate* the dose-response curve and that estimate probably should differ from the raw data, which will vary for random causes.  That's why it would be helpful to know what your model is.  We can help with the estimation, but it requires a toxicologist familiar with your experimental setting to propose and defend a model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** A standard probit regression analysis should be fine. The only thing "wrong" with your data is that the sample sizes are a bit low, so the outcomes are highly variable.

This graph shows the probit regression along with the binomial confidence intervals for the individual points (code included below since it's a little bit complicated):

[image: probit curve]

(This analysis assumes the doses are equally spaced, or equally spaced on a log scale, or in any case should be *treated* as equally spaced.)

You can see that the unusual result of 1/7 (14%) dead for dose 3, although it surprises you, is not even particularly inconsistent with the probit curve; the 95% confidence interval for a binomial probability with 1/7 deaths is (0.004, 0.58), while the predicted value from the probit is very close to 0.5. (It would unsurprising even if some of the individual binomial CIs *didn't* overlap with the curve, because we are making multiple comparisons.)

If the sample sizes were much larger, e.g. if you had 1000/7000 deaths instead of 1/7, so that the expected level of precision was much higher, then I would worry that something had gone wrong with the experiment.

The probit model can be fitted with base R (`glm(prop_dead ~ dose, data = ..., weights = n_trials, family = binomial(link="probit"))`) but you might find the `drc` package useful (or the `dose.p` function from the built-in `MASS` package, or [this link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-r-book/9780470510247/ch016-sec007.html)).

```r
dd <- data.frame(dead = c(0, 2, 1, 7, 7),
                 n = 7,
                 dose = 1:5)
dd$lwr <- dd$upr <- NA
for (i in seq(nrow(dd))) {
  bb <- binom.test(dd$dead[i], dd$n[i])
  dd$lwr[i] <- bb$conf.int[1]
  dd$upr[i] <- bb$conf.int[2]
}
```

```r
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
(ggplot(dd)
  + aes(x = dose, y = dead/n)
  + geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr))
  + geom_smooth(method = "glm",
                method.args = list(family = binomial(link = "probit")),
                aes(weight = n))
)
```

Comment: Okay, So it is the sample size. I followed OECD test guidelines (TG:203), where they have mentioned a minimum of 7 is sufficient to conduct acute toxicity test. They have mentioned for test concentration replication is not required.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't think there's anything wrong with these data (the signal appears to be strong enough to identify an LD50 (between doses 2 and 4) reasonably accurately.  You wouldn't want to sacrifice more fish than necessary.